# How can I access plugins reading in a custom python plugin for CollecD?

Tags: python, analytics, collectd

I have the follow requirement:

- Register a list of plugins in CollecD (i.e. CPU, Memory, Temp., etc);
- Every time a new metric is collected, I want to get its values and execute a command. For instance, every time a new metric about CPU usage is collected, I want - hypothetically - write it to a file;

So far my approach has been writing a custom Python plugin but I have no idea whatsoever of how I can access the reading of other plugins. For instance:

**config file**

```
LoadPlugin cpu
<Plugin cpu>
  ReportByState = true
  ReportByCpu = true
  ValuesPercentage = true
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin python
<Plugin python>
    LogTraces true
    ModulePath "/opt/collectd/plugins"
    Import "my_custom_python_plugin"
</Plugin>
```

**my_custom_python_plugin**

```
import collectd


def read_func():
  # Here I wanna execute my fancy code 
  # with the metrics collected by other plugins (i.e. CPU)


collectd.register_read(read_func)
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `write` callback from collectd is called everytime a plugin posts a metric. It contains a `values` object that can be parsed for whatever metric you want. i.e.:

**collectd.conf**

```
Hostname "graph_host"

Interval 5.0

LoadPlugin "logfile"
<Plugin "logfile">
  LogLevel "info"
  File "some/dir/log"
  Timestamp true
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin memory
<Plugin memory>
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin python
<Plugin python>
    LogTraces true
    ModulePath "/opt/collectd/plugins"
    Import "my_plugin"
</Plugin>
```

**my_plugin.py**

```
if values.plugin == "memory" and values.type == "memory" and values.type_instance == "free":
  # do whatever I want


collectd.register_write(write)
```

I haven't noticed that before because I was testing it with `cpu` plugin which had an error by itself - that permission problem that happens on Macs - therefore, no metric was being generated and `write` callback was never called.